# Testing Google App Engine ThreadManager outside of GAE

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, junit

I've written a JUnit (4.10) unit test that makes the following call to `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager`:

```
ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
```

When this test runs, I get a `NullPointerException` being thrown from within this `currentRequestThreadFactory` method:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory(ThreadManager.java:39)
    at com.myapp.server.plumbing.di.BaseModule.providesThreadFactory(BaseModule.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

When I pull down the source for `ThreadManager`, and look at Line 39 (which is the source of the NPE), I see:

```
public static ThreadFactory currentRequestThreadFactory() {
        return (ThreadFactory) ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAttributes()
            .get(REQUEST_THREAD_FACTORY_ATTR);
}
```

So it seems that the `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` is null, and when it's `getAttribute()` method is called, the NPE is thrown. I've confirmed this by adding some new print statements higher up in my unit test code:

```
if(ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment() == null)
    System.out.println("Environment is null.");
```

I'm vaguely aware that GAE offers "test versions" for all its services, but haven't been able to find (specifically) how to use them and set them up. So I ask: does GAE offer such test versions? If so, how do I add an `ApiProxy` test version here? And if not, then what are my options? I don't think I can mock either method (`ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory` or `ApiProxy#getCurrentEnvironment`)  because they're both statics. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I see that there is an `appengine-testing.jar` that ships with the SDK. Inside this JAR is an `ApiProxyLocal.class` that I *believe* is a version of `ApiProxy` that could be used during JUnit testing, that would work without throwing the NPE. If that's the case (which I'm not even sure of), then the question is: how do I inject it into my `ThreadManager` for this test?

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Introducing_the_Java_Testing_Utilities ?

Comment: Thanks again - these testing JARs (referenced in that article) give me access to local **servce** classes and methods, but not a test version of `ThreadManager`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest avoiding calling `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()` directly from your code. Instead, inject the `ThreadFactory` into the class that needs to create threads.

One easy way to do this is with Guice:

```
public static class MyService {
  private final ThreadFactory threadFactory;

  @Inject
  MyService(ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    this.threadFactory = threadFactory;
  }

  ...
}
```

In your tests for `MyService`, you could either pass a fake `ThreadFactory`to the `MyService` constructor or inject `Executors.defaultThreadFactory()`.

In your production code, you would create a binding:

```
bind(ThreadFactory.class)
    .toInstance(ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());
```

Of course, if you're not ready to jump into dependency injection, you can create your own accessors to get and set the `ThreadFactory`

Comment: Thanks @NamshubWriter, but I'm not asking *how to inject `ThreadManager`*. I'm saying that **I cannot execute `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory` from inside a JUnit test.** This is because there is an internal, uninjectably-static `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` method that is throwing a NPE. If I were to deploy my app to a local GAE app server, and then run the code, it would work fine, because then `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment()` would not throw NPEs. So I need to figure out how to get this running outside of GAE for testing purposes.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys I know what you're trying to do. I'm just suggesting going about it a completely different way. Your code depends on a static method outside your control that behaves differently in production than in a test. That makes your code hard to test. I would solve the problem by depending on a class that you do control.

Answer (score 4):

You will get the correct Threads from the stubs, if you set up your LocalServiceTestHelper, along the following lines.

```
private static final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper( new    LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

@BeforeClass
public static void initialSetup() {
    helper.setUp();
}

@AfterClass
public static void finalTearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing `ApiProxy.Environment` as suggested in
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/howto/unittesting.html

then the `getAttributes()` method is where you are not finding an
entry for `REQUEST_THREAD_FACTORY_ATTR` in your map.

You can add that:

```
attributes.put(REQUEST_THREAD_FACTORY_ATTR, new RequestThreadFactory());
```

For other helpful additions, see:
    http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/development/LocalEnvironment.java

Answer (score 0):

To add to the last answer, if you are starting a thread within your unit test case, that java thread needs the ApiProxy environment set too.

in your class LocalServiceTestCase extends TestCase, the setup method might look
something like this:

```
super.setUp();

helper1.setUp();

setEnvironment();
```

where:

```
public static void setEnvironment() {

    if (ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment() == null) {  

        ApiProxyLocal apl = LocalServiceTestHelper.getApiProxyLocal();

        ApiProxy.setEnvironmentForCurrentThread(new TEnvironment());

        ApiProxy.setDelegate(apl);

    }
}
```

The TEnvironment is given in the above urls.

You might want to make a static unsetEnvironment() too.

In your unit test case, if you've started a new java thread, you can just
use the static method at the beginning of your run method:

```
public void run() {

    LocalServiceTestCase.setEnvironment();
```